# iTunes 10.5 blocked when I connect my iPhone4

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

Today I updated iTunes to version 10.5

It starts up correctly, but when I connect my iPhone4, iTunes is blocked and the spinning wait cursor is showed....

When I disconnect iPhone, iTunes works fine....

Any idea?

Comment: Indeed doesn't belong here. FYI many users are reporting the same problem on Apple discussion website. Some let their phone connected for as long as 1 hour and eventually the sync completed fine.

Comment: Can you report the apple forum thread link?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to 10.4.1 or 10.5.1 / 10.5.2 which where pretty stable.

I don't know if you have Win or Mac, but here are the links:

iTunes 10.* for Windows: http://www.filehippo.com/download_itunes/

iTunes 10.5.1 for Mac OSX : http://appldnld.apple.com/iTunes10/041-3230.20111114.bNft5/iTunes10.5.1.dmg